# Combination AND OR result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table like this.

```
NoteID  CustomerID  CustomerName    Note                    Type    Date    Active
6       81          Paris           test                    Info    2015-06-04  1
10      81          Rotterdam       Everything is allright  Comment 2015-06-04  1
11      81          Hamburg         Everything is allright  Info    2015-06-04  1
12      81          Hamburg         Everything is allright  Info    2015-06-04  1
13      81          Amsterdam       Everything is allright  Info    2015-06-04  1
14      81          Rotterdam       Everything is allLeft   Comment 2015-06-04  1
15      81          Hamburg         Everything is allLeft   Info    2015-06-04  1
16      81          Hamburg         Everything is allLeft   Info    2015-06-04  1
17      81          Amsterdam       Everything is allLeft   Info    2015-06-04  1
```

When i execute this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM CarsNote
  WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
  AND Type != 'Comment' 
  OR Type != 'error'
```

All notes are in the result.

What I expect is that there are no notes in the result. Because of the `LIKE` statement `'%ddddddddddddddd%'`.

Can someone please explain why this query doesn't work like I expected?

Comment: use `()` like this `WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
  AND (Type != 'Comment' 
  OR Type != 'error')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure. It's called operator precedence (or more generally, operator evaluation order).

If you add parentheses, this is what you're evaluating:

```
WHERE ((Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%') AND Type != 'Comment') OR Type != 'error'
```

As per MSDN:

> When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, NOT is evaluated first, then AND, and finally OR. Arithmetic, and bitwise, operators are handled before logical operators.

The `NOT` part is great - it means you can get rid of unnecessary parentheses. The rest is a bit more trickier - `AND` will always have precedence over `OR`, all else equal. This also means that Tim's second suggestion *will actually work* - but yeah, don't do that. It's just crazy.

Even if you were aware of the rules for operatior evaluation, it's a bad idea to not make it explicit - it's just way too fragile, not to mention  hard to read (I'm currently working with codebase full of stuff like this - just *don't*. You'll save yourself and everyone else a lot of trouble in the future.). Just use this instead:

```
where Note like '%ddddddddddddddd%' or not (Type = 'Comment' or Type = 'Error')
```

or even better,

```
where Note like '%ddddddddddddddd%' and Type not in ('Comment', 'Error')
```

Comment: `NOT IN` makes the query's intention most clear in my opinion.

Comment: NOT EXISTS Performs better than NOT IN.

Comment: @HarshadVekariya Not really important, even if it were true (I'm pretty sure it isn't in a case like this). Readability first, performance only if necessary. If there's a performance problem with a query like this, `not exists` isn't going to do anything about it.

Comment: @Luaan: the `NOT IN` is the best approach but the `and (Type != 'Comment' or Type != 'Error')` doesn't work since it allows all types. It must be `and (Type != 'Comment' and Type != 'Error')`

Comment: @HarshadVekariya: `NOT EXISTS` has no issues with null values like `NOT IN`, but it is not more efficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh bugger, my bad. See, another reason to use `not in`! :D

Answer (score 7):

You have two options:

1. wrap the `OR` in paranthesis
2. repeat the `AND` + `OR`

First approach(*):

```
SELECT *
FROM CarsNote
WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
 AND (Type != 'Comment' OR Type != 'error')
```

Second:

```
SELECT *
FROM CarsNote
WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' AND Type != 'Comment' 
   OR Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' AND Type != 'error'
```

I prefer the first since it's more concise and less error-prone.

*** Important Note:** Both approaches are pointless since the combination of `!=` and `OR` is always true, it removes the filter and returns all records. So actually you have to use `AND`:

```
WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
AND (Type != 'Comment' AND Type != 'error')
```

you don't need the paranthesis with `AND`:

```
WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
  AND Type != 'Comment' AND Type != 'error'
```

If you want to include/exclude multiple values it's more readable to use `IN`/`NOT IN`:

```
WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
AND Type NOT IN('Comment', 'error')
```

Note that this skips records where the `Type` is `NULL`. Therefore you have to use:

```
WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
AND (Type IS NULL OR Type NOT IN('Comment', 'error'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Always use parantheses when you have combinations:

```
SELECT *
  FROM CarsNote
  WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
  AND (Type != 'Comment' 
  OR Type != 'error')
```

**OR** you can also use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM CarsNote
  WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
  AND Type NOT IN ('Comment','error')
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are saying with this SQL is:

> Show me all *records* with notes like d...d and not of the type 'Comment' **OR** where the type is not 'error'

The AND statement is executed *before* the OR. It could be written as:

```
(Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' AND Type != 'Comment') OR Type != 'error'
```

What I guess you would need is:

```
Note Like '%ddddddddddddddd%' AND (Type != 'Comment' OR Type != 'error')
```

Answer (score 2):

Add parentheses I mentioned in the code snippet below. The OR is causing this, because none of the Types are = 'error'

```
SELECT *
FROM CarsNote
WHERE Note LIKE '%ddddddddddddddd%' 
AND (Type != 'Comment' 
OR Type != 'error')
```

Comment: Those are parentheses, not brackets. Brackets are `[`, `]`, `{`, and `}`. The distinction is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try always to use parentheses on where clause to explicit set the order.
I believe it's the best practice.